# How to install VMware Tools in Android x86 VM?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, android, vmware-player, android-x86

I installed Android-x86 in a VMware virtual machine under Windows 7.

Is there a way to install VMWare tools in this Android-x86 VM to share files between this machine and the host? If yes, how?

Comment: use dropbox or similar, easy than ftp

Answer (score 5):

VMWare tools are not yet supported for Android, you can have a look on the guest os support matrix on the VMware website.

But you could always make a network share on your host and then get android to connect to it

Answer (score 2):

You could put your files on a flash drive and then disconnect it from host and connect it to the guest android OS.

Comment: Saved my whole day!

Comment: VM Ware does not support USB forwarding without VMware tools installed. So it is impossible to connect flash drive to android guest.

Answer (score 1):

for file sharing with your host and guest machine 
first try to connect your android vm to internet then download 
AirDroid  from google play ,now you can easily download and upload 
to your android vmware machine

Comment: Are you affiliated with the developer of this app? This looks like spam.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share files between your Windows machine and your Android VM, you could do the following:

**On your Windows machine**
1. Download TFTP at http://Sourceforge.net/Projects/TFTP-Server
2. Once installed, ensure that the service (Open TFTPServer) is in started (local services in control panel)
3. Copy files to you c:\OpenTFTPServer folder.

**In your Android VM**
1. Your Android VM should already contain the TFTP application.
2. Launch the Terminal Emulator
3. type in> su root
4. Change directory to a modifiable on> cd /sdcard/download
5. Use TFTP to copy your file from your Windows machine to your Android VM>
tftp -l  -g 
6. To verify that the file has been copied type in> ls

**Troubleshooting**
1> Ensure you're able to ping the IP of the windows machine

Answer (score 0):

I have a much simpler solution to sharing files between the Windows host and Android-x86 guest. All you need is a network sharing program that supports the Samba (SMB) protocol. I use [AndSMB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andsmb) free to download from Play Store and it is very good. You create a new connection that has your host computer name and you can give credentials or connect as Guest. To connect as Guest you could check the Anonymous box but in case this doesn't work, I give user pcname\guest and a blank password, where pcname is your computer's network name. One you open the connection you can see all the shared folder. All you have to do is copy the files you want in a shared folder which you can access from AndSMB! You can also browse all the android folders and upload any file you want to the shared folder, provided you have set read/write access rights to all users (including the Guest account).